# Why is GeoTIFF squashed in WGS84 data frame of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, arcgis-10.4

I have a government-sourced geotiff which I have imported into ArcMap 10.4 as a raster basemap. In a TIFF viewer it displays correctly but in ArcMap it appears vertically squashed by roughly 20%.

The data frame coordinate system is GCS_WGS_1984 WKID: 4326. And here is some data provided to me along with the tiff file:

Panel Limits:      Lat  -34 5 55.812    to  -33 23 59.347
                       Lon  151 7 58.170    to  151 39 42.778

```
Referencing:       Geographic Lat/Long
Spheroid:          WGS84
Horizontal Datum:  WGS 84
Scale:             1:75000

Image Size:        7258 cols x 10867 rows
Image Resolution:  254 dots-per-inch
Number of Colours: 27

TIFF Version #:    42
GeoTIFF Version #: 1
TIFF Compression:  Packbits
```

Why does it appear squashed, and how can I fix it?

I found this but it did not seem to help: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/34535. Unable to independently verify the geotiff is WGS84. I am running Windows 10 Pro under Parallels on a MacBook Pro.

What is stranger, I also have a KML map of the same area and when I alternate between the two maps in ArcMap, by disabling one of them, I can see that they are exactly coincident. In other words, both are squashed, by the same amount.

The only thought I had was that one degree of longitude, in metres, varies with the cosine of the latitude, and coincidentally 1 - cos (33.5) is about 20%. Could that have something to do with it? Clutching at straws here.

Comment: `varies with the cosine of the latitude` - Bingo! The TIFF viewer isn't taking latitude into account when showing you the image.

Comment: @Mintx: In the TIFF viewer, the map is in the correct proportions. When a Google map of the same area is overlaid, it matches on-the-ground features almost exactly. When a precise circle is overlaid on a circular compass rose on the map, that matches almost exactly also. So the TIFF viewer would appear to be doing the right thing. The problem must lie elsewhere. I presume I am right in expecting ArcMap to display the map without squashing it.

Comment: @Mintx Also, I can confirm that the degree of squashing is precisely equal to the cosine of the latitude.

Comment: Further information: In ArcMap, features are displayed with the correct latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does it appear squashed? In the TIFF viewer, the map is in the
>   correct proportions. When a Google map of the same area is overlaid,
>   it matches on-the-ground features almost exactly.

Google Maps uses a spherical Mercator projection of WGS84 lat/longs, called [WGS84 Web Mercator](http://epsg.io/3857). Earth is not a sphere, so the Web Mercator projection stretches as a function of latitude.

When you bring the image into ArcMap, it uses the [WGS84 geographic projection](http://epsg.io/4326) as stated in your data frame CRS.

Try changing your data frame to `Projected Coordinate Systems -> World -> WGS84 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)`

[image]